# Image broken - how do I display using HTML and Filezilla

Tags: html, image, filezilla

I need help. I am VERY new to learning HTML.  I created a very basic / practice HTML file; this is all I have learned so far.  I want to display an image but the image will not display.  I am using FileZilla to upload my webpage. On my desktop I have my project folder with my index file inside and another folder called images.  I uploaded this to FileZilla and uploaded again there.  Not working; need help! I really need simple precise answers as I am very very new.  Thank you!

Below is my desktop, Filezilla, my html and my page

[My desktop folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Woz.png)

[Filezilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTuTR.png)

[My HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhmJW.png)

[My Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtgGd.png)

Comment: Thank youf for your first post. It is more deficult to helpt with a question, if it provide the content in a bad way. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I suggest you put your html as text in corresponding code tag so someone can read the code and evaluate it easy with out retyping the code in the local editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the position you want to place the image in the index file. Then you can use the image tag. As the image is in a subfolder that's why you need to write the image tag like this

```
  <img src="/images/example.jpg" alt="Testing" width="600" height="400">
```

Here you can remove the height and width if you want also reshape the image size by changing height and width